# How can I make mouse wheel not work using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I stop user from using mouse wheel to scroll HTML page?

Normally we use the mouse wheel to scroll page. I the page to keep still even when user triggers the mouse wheel. What should I do?

Comment: First of all : Reason for preventing the default functionality of mouse wheel

Comment: you want to disable the scroll bar?

Comment: no,scroll bar will keep available

Comment: This will probably confuse and/or annoy the user. You want to have a very good reason before disabling default behavior, that pretty much everyone has been used to for 20+ years.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915882/disabling-mouse-scrolling-in-javascript this?

Comment: @Dennis Traub: 20- years ;). The scrollwheel was invented in 1993 at Microsoft by Eric Michelman.

Comment: @DennisTraub :D :D nice one..!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
window.onmousewheel=function(){return false}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vBCbP/