# How to disable mousewheel scroll in chrome with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used

```
$('body').bind("mousewheel", function() {
    return false;
});
```

It's working at first. but suddenly it wasn't working at all.
On chrome console wrote the issue:

"[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.
https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312"

Is there other way to disable mousewheel?
https://jsfiddle.net/7b0rzaL4/10/

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915882/disabling-mouse-scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915882/disabling-mouse-scrolling) Is a similar Question

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler way - just use `onwheel`. Try scrolling in the snippet below - you can't unless you use the scroll bar:

```js
window.onwheel = () => false;
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia est quam, in varius ipsum vulputate vitae. Nunc porttitor vulputate augue, a feugiat lorem rutrum a. Sed ac mi ultrices, tristique felis sit amet, lacinia libero. Pellentesque viverra
  quis purus eget facilisis. Donec sit amet eros pellentesque orci pulvinar egestas et quis mauris. Nam suscipit nec orci congue ultricies. Cras eleifend sem enim, a pellentesque leo tempor vel. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum non auctor felis, eu aliquet
  sem. Nullam ut urna sed lectus malesuada accumsan. Aliquam consectetur purus id ligula lacinia rhoncus. In a feugiat est.</p>

<p>Donec ut porttitor nunc, et tempus lectus. Mauris fringilla id nisi vitae lobortis. Morbi malesuada sem non mollis volutpat. Maecenas rutrum nulla nisl. Curabitur iaculis lacinia congue. Cras tortor neque, ultrices vel finibus sit amet, porttitor in metus.
  Integer eget fringilla massa. Donec dignissim nunc a sagittis vestibulum. Mauris eget nibh ut neque feugiat suscipit a nec orci.</p>

<p>Nam aliquam malesuada metus, in viverra dolor pellentesque a. Maecenas blandit rutrum diam non lacinia. Etiam magna justo, laoreet pulvinar odio eget, tristique elementum lorem. Pellentesque aliquam lacinia velit, vitae sollicitudin massa rutrum sed.
  Ut a sagittis leo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent iaculis, nisl non cursus consequat, lectus quam bibendum mi, in finibus sapien magna vel nibh. Vivamus rhoncus nisi non ex fringilla,
  eget tincidunt arcu condimentum. Aenean lobortis orci venenatis risus semper, sed malesuada ex maximus. Sed non placerat quam. Donec pulvinar neque et enim blandit, nec dignissim felis ultricies. Nulla a lacus scelerisque leo aliquet malesuada.</p>

<p>Aliquam odio erat, facilisis pharetra diam ac, tincidunt volutpat orci. Nam a nibh dapibus, dignissim mi non, bibendum libero. Duis sit amet iaculis lorem. Aenean fringilla, massa id tempor blandit, nunc diam efficitur ligula, sed luctus ligula purus
  sed erat. Etiam lacinia, velit ut tempor condimentum, sapien mi molestie risus, ornare cursus ex lorem sit amet purus. Vestibulum nibh mauris, elementum pretium vehicula quis, volutpat porttitor leo. In imperdiet, ligula id tempus euismod, nunc lectus
  bibendum purus, eget facilisis tellus nisi sit amet dui. Donec at pretium risus, sed maximus turpis. Morbi rhoncus urna erat, in sagittis velit condimentum in. Pellentesque vel facilisis lectus. Phasellus quis molestie ligula, in sodales lacus.</p>

<p>Sed scelerisque eros at metus molestie, quis molestie ex placerat. Quisque vitae feugiat lectus, sed volutpat risus. Nulla facilisi. Nunc finibus vel mi elementum aliquet. Duis vehicula lectus dui, ut rutrum lectus porttitor vulputate. Sed quis dapibus
  turpis. Maecenas volutpat lorem ut velit tempor sagittis.</p>

<p>Aenean ultricies sapien at elit tempor ornare. Sed felis mauris, dictum eget sollicitudin vel, cursus quis sem. Quisque pharetra aliquet ligula, vitae ornare lectus rhoncus in. Duis et sapien consectetur, eleifend sem volutpat, vestibulum dolor. Sed feugiat
  maximus augue, eget scelerisque nisi posuere eget. Donec egestas, dui non pellentesque bibendum, augue quam consequat augue, vel malesuada turpis lectus in nunc. Curabitur non lacinia dui.</p>

<p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In venenatis ipsum at nunc blandit sagittis. Vestibulum consectetur eu ipsum at semper. Nulla a eros elit. Phasellus ut elit quis leo mollis feugiat eget id mi. Fusce dignissim ultrices nibh, sit amet euismod odio vulputate
  eget. Morbi velit ante, interdum a ante id, facilisis bibendum elit. Fusce ac massa bibendum, suscipit quam quis, vestibulum ante. Nunc sit amet magna vel dui commodo pellentesque vel vitae lacus.</p>

<p>Nam lobortis diam eget magna aliquet pretium. Donec tincidunt tristique erat a tincidunt. Nam ac lectus et dolor rutrum consequat. Integer sed nunc suscipit erat venenatis malesuada et gravida turpis. Phasellus nec felis quis lectus sollicitudin finibus.
  Aliquam bibendum eu nibh ut tincidunt. In pharetra nisl quis metus aliquet lobortis. Donec consequat elit sit amet velit rutrum tempor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc tincidunt justo nec
  metus aliquet, in pretium magna venenatis. Mauris id tellus pharetra felis dapibus dictum a in elit. In eu viverra purus, id bibendum dolor. Nunc eleifend metus eu tortor accumsan, at ullamcorper leo tincidunt. Suspendisse sit amet posuere magna. Sed
  vitae ullamcorper libero, eu volutpat orci. Sed viverra placerat nunc, sit amet efficitur dolor aliquet ac.</p>

<p>Nulla facilisis non eros vel aliquet. Morbi finibus libero tincidunt nisl porta feugiat. In ut suscipit orci. Nunc vulputate, diam nec blandit lobortis, tortor diam facilisis turpis, non volutpat sapien massa nec augue. Phasellus et dolor in elit cursus
  consequat. Etiam auctor, eros at blandit consequat, nisi neque ultricies justo, id rutrum urna lacus at velit. Aliquam hendrerit maximus ligula sed laoreet. Donec ultrices dignissim lectus, quis rhoncus massa viverra ut.</p>

<p>Fusce tristique sapien vitae nibh sodales hendrerit. Proin tincidunt iaculis ante ac dignissim. Vestibulum a finibus dui. Pellentesque at eleifend lorem. Fusce in magna imperdiet, dignissim enim sit amet, auctor nisl. Aliquam pharetra orci non vulputate
  convallis. Donec a ante semper, dapibus lectus a, pulvinar lorem. Morbi ut bibendum ligula.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia est quam, in varius ipsum vulputate vitae. Nunc porttitor vulputate augue, a feugiat lorem rutrum a. Sed ac mi ultrices, tristique felis sit amet, lacinia libero. Pellentesque viverra
  quis purus eget facilisis. Donec sit amet eros pellentesque orci pulvinar egestas et quis mauris. Nam suscipit nec orci congue ultricies. Cras eleifend sem enim, a pellentesque leo tempor vel. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum non auctor felis, eu aliquet
  sem. Nullam ut urna sed lectus malesuada accumsan. Aliquam consectetur purus id ligula lacinia rhoncus. In a feugiat est.</p>

<p>Donec ut porttitor nunc, et tempus lectus. Mauris fringilla id nisi vitae lobortis. Morbi malesuada sem non mollis volutpat. Maecenas rutrum nulla nisl. Curabitur iaculis lacinia congue. Cras tortor neque, ultrices vel finibus sit amet, porttitor in metus.
  Integer eget fringilla massa. Donec dignissim nunc a sagittis vestibulum. Mauris eget nibh ut neque feugiat suscipit a nec orci.</p>

<p>Nam aliquam malesuada metus, in viverra dolor pellentesque a. Maecenas blandit rutrum diam non lacinia. Etiam magna justo, laoreet pulvinar odio eget, tristique elementum lorem. Pellentesque aliquam lacinia velit, vitae sollicitudin massa rutrum sed.
  Ut a sagittis leo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent iaculis, nisl non cursus consequat, lectus quam bibendum mi, in finibus sapien magna vel nibh. Vivamus rhoncus nisi non ex fringilla,
  eget tincidunt arcu condimentum. Aenean lobortis orci venenatis risus semper, sed malesuada ex maximus. Sed non placerat quam. Donec pulvinar neque et enim blandit, nec dignissim felis ultricies. Nulla a lacus scelerisque leo aliquet malesuada.</p>

<p>Aliquam odio erat, facilisis pharetra diam ac, tincidunt volutpat orci. Nam a nibh dapibus, dignissim mi non, bibendum libero. Duis sit amet iaculis lorem. Aenean fringilla, massa id tempor blandit, nunc diam efficitur ligula, sed luctus ligula purus
  sed erat. Etiam lacinia, velit ut tempor condimentum, sapien mi molestie risus, ornare cursus ex lorem sit amet purus. Vestibulum nibh mauris, elementum pretium vehicula quis, volutpat porttitor leo. In imperdiet, ligula id tempus euismod, nunc lectus
  bibendum purus, eget facilisis tellus nisi sit amet dui. Donec at pretium risus, sed maximus turpis. Morbi rhoncus urna erat, in sagittis velit condimentum in. Pellentesque vel facilisis lectus. Phasellus quis molestie ligula, in sodales lacus.</p>

<p>Sed scelerisque eros at metus molestie, quis molestie ex placerat. Quisque vitae feugiat lectus, sed volutpat risus. Nulla facilisi. Nunc finibus vel mi elementum aliquet. Duis vehicula lectus dui, ut rutrum lectus porttitor vulputate. Sed quis dapibus
  turpis. Maecenas volutpat lorem ut velit tempor sagittis.</p>

<p>Aenean ultricies sapien at elit tempor ornare. Sed felis mauris, dictum eget sollicitudin vel, cursus quis sem. Quisque pharetra aliquet ligula, vitae ornare lectus rhoncus in. Duis et sapien consectetur, eleifend sem volutpat, vestibulum dolor. Sed feugiat
  maximus augue, eget scelerisque nisi posuere eget. Donec egestas, dui non pellentesque bibendum, augue quam consequat augue, vel malesuada turpis lectus in nunc. Curabitur non lacinia dui.</p>

<p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In venenatis ipsum at nunc blandit sagittis. Vestibulum consectetur eu ipsum at semper. Nulla a eros elit. Phasellus ut elit quis leo mollis feugiat eget id mi. Fusce dignissim ultrices nibh, sit amet euismod odio vulputate
  eget. Morbi velit ante, interdum a ante id, facilisis bibendum elit. Fusce ac massa bibendum, suscipit quam quis, vestibulum ante. Nunc sit amet magna vel dui commodo pellentesque vel vitae lacus.</p>

<p>Nam lobortis diam eget magna aliquet pretium. Donec tincidunt tristique erat a tincidunt. Nam ac lectus et dolor rutrum consequat. Integer sed nunc suscipit erat venenatis malesuada et gravida turpis. Phasellus nec felis quis lectus sollicitudin finibus.
  Aliquam bibendum eu nibh ut tincidunt. In pharetra nisl quis metus aliquet lobortis. Donec consequat elit sit amet velit rutrum tempor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc tincidunt justo nec
  metus aliquet, in pretium magna venenatis. Mauris id tellus pharetra felis dapibus dictum a in elit. In eu viverra purus, id bibendum dolor. Nunc eleifend metus eu tortor accumsan, at ullamcorper leo tincidunt. Suspendisse sit amet posuere magna. Sed
  vitae ullamcorper libero, eu volutpat orci. Sed viverra placerat nunc, sit amet efficitur dolor aliquet ac.</p>

<p>Nulla facilisis non eros vel aliquet. Morbi finibus libero tincidunt nisl porta feugiat. In ut suscipit orci. Nunc vulputate, diam nec blandit lobortis, tortor diam facilisis turpis, non volutpat sapien massa nec augue. Phasellus et dolor in elit cursus
  consequat. Etiam auctor, eros at blandit consequat, nisi neque ultricies justo, id rutrum urna lacus at velit. Aliquam hendrerit maximus ligula sed laoreet. Donec ultrices dignissim lectus, quis rhoncus massa viverra ut.</p>

<p>Fusce tristique sapien vitae nibh sodales hendrerit. Proin tincidunt iaculis ante ac dignissim. Vestibulum a finibus dui. Pellentesque at eleifend lorem. Fusce in magna imperdiet, dignissim enim sit amet, auctor nisl. Aliquam pharetra orci non vulputate
  convallis. Donec a ante semper, dapibus lectus a, pulvinar lorem. Morbi ut bibendum ligula.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia est quam, in varius ipsum vulputate vitae. Nunc porttitor vulputate augue, a feugiat lorem rutrum a. Sed ac mi ultrices, tristique felis sit amet, lacinia libero. Pellentesque viverra
  quis purus eget facilisis. Donec sit amet eros pellentesque orci pulvinar egestas et quis mauris. Nam suscipit nec orci congue ultricies. Cras eleifend sem enim, a pellentesque leo tempor vel. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum non auctor felis, eu aliquet
  sem. Nullam ut urna sed lectus malesuada accumsan. Aliquam consectetur purus id ligula lacinia rhoncus. In a feugiat est.</p>

<p>Donec ut porttitor nunc, et tempus lectus. Mauris fringilla id nisi vitae lobortis. Morbi malesuada sem non mollis volutpat. Maecenas rutrum nulla nisl. Curabitur iaculis lacinia congue. Cras tortor neque, ultrices vel finibus sit amet, porttitor in metus.
  Integer eget fringilla massa. Donec dignissim nunc a sagittis vestibulum. Mauris eget nibh ut neque feugiat suscipit a nec orci.</p>

<p>Nam aliquam malesuada metus, in viverra dolor pellentesque a. Maecenas blandit rutrum diam non lacinia. Etiam magna justo, laoreet pulvinar odio eget, tristique elementum lorem. Pellentesque aliquam lacinia velit, vitae sollicitudin massa rutrum sed.
  Ut a sagittis leo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent iaculis, nisl non cursus consequat, lectus quam bibendum mi, in finibus sapien magna vel nibh. Vivamus rhoncus nisi non ex fringilla,
  eget tincidunt arcu condimentum. Aenean lobortis orci venenatis risus semper, sed malesuada ex maximus. Sed non placerat quam. Donec pulvinar neque et enim blandit, nec dignissim felis ultricies. Nulla a lacus scelerisque leo aliquet malesuada.</p>

<p>Aliquam odio erat, facilisis pharetra diam ac, tincidunt volutpat orci. Nam a nibh dapibus, dignissim mi non, bibendum libero. Duis sit amet iaculis lorem. Aenean fringilla, massa id tempor blandit, nunc diam efficitur ligula, sed luctus ligula purus
  sed erat. Etiam lacinia, velit ut tempor condimentum, sapien mi molestie risus, ornare cursus ex lorem sit amet purus. Vestibulum nibh mauris, elementum pretium vehicula quis, volutpat porttitor leo. In imperdiet, ligula id tempus euismod, nunc lectus
  bibendum purus, eget facilisis tellus nisi sit amet dui. Donec at pretium risus, sed maximus turpis. Morbi rhoncus urna erat, in sagittis velit condimentum in. Pellentesque vel facilisis lectus. Phasellus quis molestie ligula, in sodales lacus.</p>

<p>Sed scelerisque eros at metus molestie, quis molestie ex placerat. Quisque vitae feugiat lectus, sed volutpat risus. Nulla facilisi. Nunc finibus vel mi elementum aliquet. Duis vehicula lectus dui, ut rutrum lectus porttitor vulputate. Sed quis dapibus
  turpis. Maecenas volutpat lorem ut velit tempor sagittis.</p>

<p>Aenean ultricies sapien at elit tempor ornare. Sed felis mauris, dictum eget sollicitudin vel, cursus quis sem. Quisque pharetra aliquet ligula, vitae ornare lectus rhoncus in. Duis et sapien consectetur, eleifend sem volutpat, vestibulum dolor. Sed feugiat
  maximus augue, eget scelerisque nisi posuere eget. Donec egestas, dui non pellentesque bibendum, augue quam consequat augue, vel malesuada turpis lectus in nunc. Curabitur non lacinia dui.</p>

<p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In venenatis ipsum at nunc blandit sagittis. Vestibulum consectetur eu ipsum at semper. Nulla a eros elit. Phasellus ut elit quis leo mollis feugiat eget id mi. Fusce dignissim ultrices nibh, sit amet euismod odio vulputate
  eget. Morbi velit ante, interdum a ante id, facilisis bibendum elit. Fusce ac massa bibendum, suscipit quam quis, vestibulum ante. Nunc sit amet magna vel dui commodo pellentesque vel vitae lacus.</p>

<p>Nam lobortis diam eget magna aliquet pretium. Donec tincidunt tristique erat a tincidunt. Nam ac lectus et dolor rutrum consequat. Integer sed nunc suscipit erat venenatis malesuada et gravida turpis. Phasellus nec felis quis lectus sollicitudin finibus.
  Aliquam bibendum eu nibh ut tincidunt. In pharetra nisl quis metus aliquet lobortis. Donec consequat elit sit amet velit rutrum tempor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc tincidunt justo nec
  metus aliquet, in pretium magna venenatis. Mauris id tellus pharetra felis dapibus dictum a in elit. In eu viverra purus, id bibendum dolor. Nunc eleifend metus eu tortor accumsan, at ullamcorper leo tincidunt. Suspendisse sit amet posuere magna. Sed
  vitae ullamcorper libero, eu volutpat orci. Sed viverra placerat nunc, sit amet efficitur dolor aliquet ac.</p>

<p>Nulla facilisis non eros vel aliquet. Morbi finibus libero tincidunt nisl porta feugiat. In ut suscipit orci. Nunc vulputate, diam nec blandit lobortis, tortor diam facilisis turpis, non volutpat sapien massa nec augue. Phasellus et dolor in elit cursus
  consequat. Etiam auctor, eros at blandit consequat, nisi neque ultricies justo, id rutrum urna lacus at velit. Aliquam hendrerit maximus ligula sed laoreet. Donec ultrices dignissim lectus, quis rhoncus massa viverra ut.</p>

<p>Fusce tristique sapien vitae nibh sodales hendrerit. Proin tincidunt iaculis ante ac dignissim. Vestibulum a finibus dui. Pellentesque at eleifend lorem. Fusce in magna imperdiet, dignissim enim sit amet, auctor nisl. Aliquam pharetra orci non vulputate
  convallis. Donec a ante semper, dapibus lectus a, pulvinar lorem. Morbi ut bibendum ligula.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent lacinia est quam, in varius ipsum vulputate vitae. Nunc porttitor vulputate augue, a feugiat lorem rutrum a. Sed ac mi ultrices, tristique felis sit amet, lacinia libero. Pellentesque viverra
  quis purus eget facilisis. Donec sit amet eros pellentesque orci pulvinar egestas et quis mauris. Nam suscipit nec orci congue ultricies. Cras eleifend sem enim, a pellentesque leo tempor vel. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum non auctor felis, eu aliquet
  sem. Nullam ut urna sed lectus malesuada accumsan. Aliquam consectetur purus id ligula lacinia rhoncus. In a feugiat est.</p>

<p>Donec ut porttitor nunc, et tempus lectus. Mauris fringilla id nisi vitae lobortis. Morbi malesuada sem non mollis volutpat. Maecenas rutrum nulla nisl. Curabitur iaculis lacinia congue. Cras tortor neque, ultrices vel finibus sit amet, porttitor in metus.
  Integer eget fringilla massa. Donec dignissim nunc a sagittis vestibulum. Mauris eget nibh ut neque feugiat suscipit a nec orci.</p>

<p>Nam aliquam malesuada metus, in viverra dolor pellentesque a. Maecenas blandit rutrum diam non lacinia. Etiam magna justo, laoreet pulvinar odio eget, tristique elementum lorem. Pellentesque aliquam lacinia velit, vitae sollicitudin massa rutrum sed.
  Ut a sagittis leo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent iaculis, nisl non cursus consequat, lectus quam bibendum mi, in finibus sapien magna vel nibh. Vivamus rhoncus nisi non ex fringilla,
  eget tincidunt arcu condimentum. Aenean lobortis orci venenatis risus semper, sed malesuada ex maximus. Sed non placerat quam. Donec pulvinar neque et enim blandit, nec dignissim felis ultricies. Nulla a lacus scelerisque leo aliquet malesuada.</p>

<p>Aliquam odio erat, facilisis pharetra diam ac, tincidunt volutpat orci. Nam a nibh dapibus, dignissim mi non, bibendum libero. Duis sit amet iaculis lorem. Aenean fringilla, massa id tempor blandit, nunc diam efficitur ligula, sed luctus ligula purus
  sed erat. Etiam lacinia, velit ut tempor condimentum, sapien mi molestie risus, ornare cursus ex lorem sit amet purus. Vestibulum nibh mauris, elementum pretium vehicula quis, volutpat porttitor leo. In imperdiet, ligula id tempus euismod, nunc lectus
  bibendum purus, eget facilisis tellus nisi sit amet dui. Donec at pretium risus, sed maximus turpis. Morbi rhoncus urna erat, in sagittis velit condimentum in. Pellentesque vel facilisis lectus. Phasellus quis molestie ligula, in sodales lacus.</p>

<p>Sed scelerisque eros at metus molestie, quis molestie ex placerat. Quisque vitae feugiat lectus, sed volutpat risus. Nulla facilisi. Nunc finibus vel mi elementum aliquet. Duis vehicula lectus dui, ut rutrum lectus porttitor vulputate. Sed quis dapibus
  turpis. Maecenas volutpat lorem ut velit tempor sagittis.</p>

<p>Aenean ultricies sapien at elit tempor ornare. Sed felis mauris, dictum eget sollicitudin vel, cursus quis sem. Quisque pharetra aliquet ligula, vitae ornare lectus rhoncus in. Duis et sapien consectetur, eleifend sem volutpat, vestibulum dolor. Sed feugiat
  maximus augue, eget scelerisque nisi posuere eget. Donec egestas, dui non pellentesque bibendum, augue quam consequat augue, vel malesuada turpis lectus in nunc. Curabitur non lacinia dui.</p>

<p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In venenatis ipsum at nunc blandit sagittis. Vestibulum consectetur eu ipsum at semper. Nulla a eros elit. Phasellus ut elit quis leo mollis feugiat eget id mi. Fusce dignissim ultrices nibh, sit amet euismod odio vulputate
  eget. Morbi velit ante, interdum a ante id, facilisis bibendum elit. Fusce ac massa bibendum, suscipit quam quis, vestibulum ante. Nunc sit amet magna vel dui commodo pellentesque vel vitae lacus.</p>

<p>Nam lobortis diam eget magna aliquet pretium. Donec tincidunt tristique erat a tincidunt. Nam ac lectus et dolor rutrum consequat. Integer sed nunc suscipit erat venenatis malesuada et gravida turpis. Phasellus nec felis quis lectus sollicitudin finibus.
  Aliquam bibendum eu nibh ut tincidunt. In pharetra nisl quis metus aliquet lobortis. Donec consequat elit sit amet velit rutrum tempor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc tincidunt justo nec
  metus aliquet, in pretium magna venenatis. Mauris id tellus pharetra felis dapibus dictum a in elit. In eu viverra purus, id bibendum dolor. Nunc eleifend metus eu tortor accumsan, at ullamcorper leo tincidunt. Suspendisse sit amet posuere magna. Sed
  vitae ullamcorper libero, eu volutpat orci. Sed viverra placerat nunc, sit amet efficitur dolor aliquet ac.</p>

<p>Nulla facilisis non eros vel aliquet. Morbi finibus libero tincidunt nisl porta feugiat. In ut suscipit orci. Nunc vulputate, diam nec blandit lobortis, tortor diam facilisis turpis, non volutpat sapien massa nec augue. Phasellus et dolor in elit cursus
  consequat. Etiam auctor, eros at blandit consequat, nisi neque ultricies justo, id rutrum urna lacus at velit. Aliquam hendrerit maximus ligula sed laoreet. Donec ultrices dignissim lectus, quis rhoncus massa viverra ut.</p>

<p>Fusce tristique sapien vitae nibh sodales hendrerit. Proin tincidunt iaculis ante ac dignissim. Vestibulum a finibus dui. Pellentesque at eleifend lorem. Fusce in magna imperdiet, dignissim enim sit amet, auctor nisl. Aliquam pharetra orci non vulputate
  convallis. Donec a ante semper, dapibus lectus a, pulvinar lorem. Morbi ut bibendum ligula.</p>
```

Comment: Scrolls just fine with the mousewheel for me.

Comment: @duskwuff doesn't happen for me - try entering it in the console in a page and see if that happens as well. What browser and OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this

```
    $(window).on("mousewheel", function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    } else if (e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY < 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }    
});
```

Comment: I tried it, mouse wheel scrolls just fine for me, Chrome's console wrote the same issue.

Comment: try  `touch-action: none` it should solve it